# Android extend default locale

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

I have inherited an old android app, and the first thing I did, was change the build from Ant to gradle. 
The app builds fine, but when I try to run the release target, gradle fails complaining about missing translations.

The folder structure of the resource folder is: (the default language, in the values folder is en-GB)

```
res/
   values/
        /file1.xml
        /file2.xml
        /file3.xml
   /values-us/
        /file2.xml (containing just the few lines that differ from /value/file2.xml
   /values-dk/
         file1.xml
         file2.xml
         file3.xml
```

So, basically the linter is correct, most of the files are missing in the values-us folder. 
However, a single locale contains about 20 files, with around 100+ lines each, and the difference between the default and US is probably 5 lines total, it seems impractical to have to maintain all values for both locales. 
To be clear, I absolutely want the release target to fail, when values-dk/ or values-de/ are missing translations, I's just like some way to mark the US locale as an extension of the default. Is this possible?

Comment: Set the attribute `translatable="false"` on your not-to-be-translated strings (in `en-GB`). Same goes for your (eventual) string-arrays.

Comment: thanks for the input, but I'd actually like the linter to run where it makes sense, f.x. in any non english values folders.
I've added some more info to the original question

Comment: ... well, it already does so. In non-English folders, Lint complains for untranslated strings. But, if the strings are marked as "untranslatable" (in the English folder), it won't anymore complain on such words.

Comment: The strings aren't untranslateable, the linter should validate that they are translated to. f.x. dk or de locale. marking them (and since so few actually needs to be translated from gb -->  us it would be pretty much every string) as untranslateable would make the linter irrelevant

Comment: So, I don't get your point. If you want to translate from English to anything else, do that. The strings which don't need to be translated to any other language, should be marked. Pretty straight, isn't it?

Comment: I had my doubts about how to phrase this question, and apparently I failed. I've tried to clear it up, hope it helps. 
Anyway. All the strings need to be translated. and I totally want the linter to fail if they're not. I'd just like to be able to mark the US locale as an extension of the default (which is GB). since that's what it is 99,8% of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this is actually pretty simple. All I had to do was rename the values-us/ folder to values-en-rUS/ and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think Lint found some strings that are not in res/values but in res/values-{language}. In this case, if the code tries to use one of those strings and the string selection falls to default one (phone is set to a language where you don't provide translations), the application will crash.

The error should tell you which string is not translated. I'd start by checking the languages defining it and make sure it's also in the default ones.

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around, the default has values that the localizations are missing. Sorry if the question was phrased poorly. I've tried to add a little more info to it, that, hopefully, should make it slightly less ambigious